# React Leaflet Google Map Partial and Incomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, leaflet

I'm trying to learn something and develop a google map project with react-leaflet using JavaScript. I've made a simple React app and implemented the simple google map layer. Maps however are only drawn partially.

[image: Failed Map]

There are no errors neither in the vs code or the console.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const center = [41.015137, 28.97953]; // Set your initial map center coordinates

function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={center}
      zoom={13}
      style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url={`https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&hl=en&gl=US&${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`}
        subdomains={["mt0", "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"]}
      />
      <Marker position={center}>
        <Popup>A sample marker on the map.</Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also believe that the problem is not related to the API key since it worked well with @react-google-maps/api.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps may not provide map tiles in the same way as some other map providers, so using the same URL template might not work. Instead, you can use a different map provider or service that is compatible with React-Leaflet.
See the code above how you can use a Mapbox tile layer:

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const center = [41.015137, 28.97953]; // Set center coordinates

function App() {
    return (
        <MapContainer
            center={center}
            zoom={13}
            style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}
        >
            <TileLayer
                url="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}"
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a>'
                id="replace to your-mapbox-style-id"
                accessToken="replace to your-mapbox-access-token"
            />
            <Marker position={center}>
                <Popup>A marker on the map.</Popup>
            </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[freecodecamp link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-a-custom-mapbox-basemap-with-gatsby-and-react-leaflet/)

Comment: But I need to use google map since I am going to implement my project to the other one which is already used @react-google-maps/api.